# Filter Widget using QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt3

I want to implement Filter widget using QComboBox. The way it should work is, when I type letter 'a' it should show the items that are starting with 'a', and then if I type 'b' it should show the items that have the prefix 'ab' etc. I tried by overriding `keyPressEvent` of `QComboBox` class, but it didn't work. The main problem I got is, how can I make the `QComboBox` editable while the drop down list is appearing ? I'm opening dropdown list inside the key press event like this,

```
void SearchCombo::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    ...
    listBox()->popup();
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is a Filter widget? Is it a standard type of widget (on other platforms, but not available in Qt), or did you make up the name yourself? If it's something standard, you can post links to examples of it.

Comment: No. it is not a standard widget. I put that name because it will search and filter combobox items as i type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. What i did is, passing the `QListBox`'s (`QComboBox` has a listbox) keyPressEvent's `QKeyEvent` to the `QComboBox`'s LineEdit. Inside the LineEdit overrode `keyPressEvent` called using that `QKeyEvent`